# Looking for BIDS functionality in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am working with SSRS 2005 and have created a report in BIDS.  The report contains an image in the details area with several fields from a dataset placed over top of the image.  Obviously when the report is run the image repeats itself with the data from each row placed over top of this image.

What I want to know is if there is any way to get this type of functionality in Report Builder so that an end user could create these kinds of reports on the fly.  From what I have seen it doesn't appear to be possible. I can certainly insert images onto the report but there doesn't seem to be a way to have it repeated for each row of data like I am doing in BIDS.  Is this feature available in ANY version of SSRS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to place fields over the top of an image to have it repeat.

If you have a table on your report it must be linked to a dataset.
In the details section, inserting an image into one of the fields will cause it to be repeated for as many rows as there are in the dataset. 
If you insert an image into a table at a group level then it will repeat for each group.

I've just tried this on both BIDS (2008 R2) and Report Builder 3.0

(My dataset has 5 rows, I've typed "Details row" into the second column on the details row)

[image]

Comment: Quite right but having the data appear at specific points over top of the image is what I am trying to achieve.  It is a trivial thing to do in BIDS but would like the end user to be able to do this.  Unfortunately it doesn't appear possible in Report Builder.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "having the data appear at specific points over top of the image"? Have you tried creating a report in BIDS and opening it in report builder?

Comment: Reports created in BIDS can't be opened in Report Builder. As far as printing fields over an image I mean that quite literally.  Think of a  Banking Check and how the placement of the fields would need to be very specific to print an accurate check.  It is a similar principal; the image is a graphical representation of where the user would need to place XYZ fields to get the fields to print in a certain manner at certain locations on the paper.

Comment: If you had 2008 or newer then you'd be able to open a BIDS report in Report Builder. The 2005 version is pretty limited. In 2008 and above you can navigate to the report and in the drop down menu there's an option to 'edit in report builder'. If you could explain what you are doing in BIDS to achieve the fields placed in specific places over the image this then that might help. It sounds problematic using fields from the details rows if your dataset is variable. I'm guessing you are using the image as a background with a table in front of it, but could you be clearer about that?